# Reduce matrix with imaginary numbers

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, gaussian-elimination

> Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix
>   $$
>     \begin{bmatrix}
>     -3 & 3 \\
>     -6 & 3 
>     \end{bmatrix}
> $$

I found the eigenvalues $$λ = ±3i$$
However, I am having trouble with finding the eigenvectors. I tried checking steps with online calculators but I couldn't quite follow what was being done.

The matrix for $λ=3i$:
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -3-3i & 3 \\
    -6 & 3-3i 
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I began by dividing $R_1$ with $(-3-3i)$ to get the first element to be $1$.

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & \frac{1}{(-1-i)} \\
    -6 & 3-3i 
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Now I would multiply $R_1$ with 6 and subtract that from $R_2$, but that doesn't give me the correct eigenvector. How should I reduce this matrix?

The answer should be:
$$v_1=
    \begin{bmatrix}
     1  \\
    1 +i
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$v_2=
    \begin{bmatrix}
     1  \\
    1 -i
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn’t you want to _add_ $6R_1$ to $R_2$ instead of subtracting? It would also be helpful if you included the result that you think is incorrect in your question. It might be OK after all: recall that there’s no such thing as _the_ eigenvector and you might have found a scalar multiple of what’s in the answer key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that$$\frac1{-1-i}=-\frac12+\frac i2$$and that therefore the second line of the matrix $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&\frac1{-1-i}\\-6&3-3i\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ is the first line times $-6$. So, solving the equation $x+\frac y{-1-i}=0$ is the same thing as solving the equation $-6x+(3-3i)y=0$. One solution will be $(1,1+i)$, since $1+\frac{1+i}{-1-i}=1-1=0$.

Comment: How is $\frac{1}{-1-i} = \frac{-1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}$?

Comment: Since, if $a+bi\neq0$, $\frac1{a+bi}=\frac a{a^2+b^2}-\frac b{a^2+b^2}i$,$$\frac1{-1-i}=\frac{-1}{(-1)^2+(-1)^2}-\frac{-1}{(-1)^2+(-1)^2}i=-\frac12+\frac i2.$$

Comment: Thank you very much!